# Comandos personalizados discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

tengo una duda, como puedo hacer que al poner un comando, este agrege uno, algo asi

```
!addcommand Besar El usuario {} ha besado a {}
```

Y ese comando cuando ponga
**!besar** diga el mensaje que especifique

Comment: Lo que propones debería ser posible. El comando `addcommand` debería guardar por ejemplo en un `csv` la información necesaria para crear el comando (nombre, parámetros, mensaje a enviar) con un formato concreto. Cuando se reinicie el bot, por ejemplo en el evento `on_ready()` se podría leer el `csv` con la información de los comandos y crearlos dinámicamente. No obstante, este último paso parece bastante complicado para la limitación de funcionalidad que tendrían los comandos guardados en el `csv`. En mi opinión, deberías descartar la idea y programar los comandos "manualmente".

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Ha besado a {0.user}'.format(client))
    
client.run('token')
```